# GWT Deploying to Google has encountered a fault

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

Got an error I can't fix.  Looks like a memory issue but the stack trace is kind of looping as if the is an infinite loop in the compilation?

Running Eclipse Juno
Working with Google App engine.

I get an error when I try to deploy one app to GAE however another Google App Engine app works.

Errors I see:
GWT compilation failed

The site.xml file downloaded from the update site does not contain any  elements with an id of 'com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.e42.feature'. Unable to determine if there are updates available.

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data C:\Users\myuser\workspacejuno -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


[ERROR] Failure in unit cache map load.
```

And the complete stack dump/trace:

```
[ERROR] Failure in unit cache map load.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.awaitUnitCacheMapLoad(PersistentUnitCache.java:466)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.find(PersistentUnitCache.java:391)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.addArchive(CompilationStateBuilder.java:365)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ArchivePreloader.preloadArchives(ArchivePreloader.java:65)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:243)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:159)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.readObject(DiskCacheToken.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)


[loops this a few time, sorry could not post it all, its too long.

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
onStateBuilder.java:466)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:388)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:246)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possibly related to a corrupted cache. Delete your gwt-UnitCache folder. If that doesn't work, delete your AppData\Local\Temp files as well (if under Windows) since there are many gwt-generated files there.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive if it is too obvious or out of topic, but did you try to set or modify compiler directive: jvmarg -Xss ?

Something like `<jvmarg value="-Xss16M"/>` in your build.xml file may help here.